# Saving and retrieving signatures in Flutter stepper form using syncfusion_flutter_signaturepad

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form implemented within a Flutter Stepper, and within this form, there's a SignaturePad from the syncfusion_flutter_signaturepad package. I'm looking for a way to persist the user's signature so that it can be loaded when the user returns to the form.

Currently, I can successfully save and retrieve text and date values even if the user closes the form. However, when it comes to the signature, I only know how to save it as an image but struggle with retrieving it to display within the form for the user.
Currently, my workaround is to display the image of the signature below the SignaturePad, but I'm not convinced it's the optimal solution.

I'm specifically using the syncfusion_flutter_signaturepad package for handling signatures.

Thanks in advance for your help !